# Showing that a Markov-Chain has this property.

Tags: probability, markov-chains

So I have to show that: Let  $\{X_n\}$ be a Markov chain. Show that the property  $P(X_{n+1}=i|X_n=j_n,X_0=j_0)=P(X_{n+1}=i|X_n=j_n)$ holds. Hint: use the Markov-property. The Markov Property being: $P(X_{n+1}=i|X_n=j_n,X_{n-1}=j_{n-1},...,X_1=j_1,X_0=j_0)=P(X_{n+1}=i|X_n=j_n)$

---

Isn't this kinda obvious? I mean the Markov property says that the last state is only dependent on the forelast state. What is here to prove? Isn't that too easy? What am I missing?

Comment: It's as easy as you think it is.

Comment: bot how would I formally prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $j_0, i, j_n$. By Markov property, for all $j_{n - 1}, \ldots, j_1 \in S$, where $S$ denotes the state space of this Markov chain, we have
\begin{align}
P[X_{n + 1} = i \mid X_n = j_n, X_{n - 1} = j_{n - 1}, \ldots, X_0 = j_0] = P[X_{n + 1} = i \mid X_n = j_n].
\end{align}
Or equivalently,
\begin{align}
& P[X_{n + 1} = i, X_n = j_n, X_{n - 1} = j_{n - 1}, \ldots, X_0 = j_0] \\
= & P[X_{n + 1} = i \mid X_n = j_n]P[X_n = j_n, X_{n - 1} = j_{n - 1}, \ldots, X_0 = j_0]. \tag{1}
\end{align}
Now, summing $j_{n - 1}$ over $S$ on both sides of $(1)$ gives
\begin{align}
& P[X_{n + 1} = i, X_n = j_n, X_{n - 2} = j_{n - 2}, \ldots, X_0 = j_0] \\
= & P[X_{n + 1} = i \mid X_n = j_n]P[X_n = j_n, X_{n - 2} = j_{n - 2}, \ldots, X_0 = j_0]. \tag{2}
\end{align}
Next, summing $j_{n - 2}$ over $S$ on both sides of $(2)$ gives
\begin{align}
& P[X_{n + 1} = i, X_n = j_n, X_{n - 3} = j_{n - 3}, \ldots, X_0 = j_0] \\
= & P[X_{n + 1} = i \mid X_n = j_n]P[X_n = j_n, X_{n - 3} = j_{n - 3}, \ldots, X_0 = j_0]. 
\end{align} 
Continue in this way recursively to finally deduce that
$$P[X_{n + 1} = i, X_n = j_n, X_0 = j_0] = P[X_{n + 1} = i \mid X_n = j_n] P[X_n = j_n, X_0 = j_0]$$
that is,
\begin{align}
P[X_{n + 1} = i \mid X_n = j_n, X_0 = j_0] = P[X_{n + 1} = i \mid X_n = j_n].
\end{align}

Comment: you showed the markov property, not the property I was asking for.

Comment: @Lawg Please see my edited (new) answer. I apologize for made a naive mistake.